# How to do object recognition with kinect?

Tags: ros, kinect, object-recognition, object-detection

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I would like to combine both RGB and Depth information in object detection and recognition application. I have found package such as rein, object_recognition...etc. But I haven't figure out how to combine them to do the task. Does anyone has experience with this?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/9304/how-to-do-object-recognition-with-kinect?/) by [peterkty](https://answers.ros.org/users/245/peterkty/) on ROS Answers with karma: 61 on 2011-03-06

Post score: 6

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You can see tod_* packages (textured object detection). It gives good detection rate on Kinect data.

---

Originally posted by [Alexander Shishkov](https://answers.ros.org/users/334/alexander-shishkov/) with karma: 191 on 2011-03-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0